# Correct syntax for bash function as alias in .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, alias

I have just read the following instruction in a bash scripting [tutorial](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_wss0020.php):

> Let's try one. Open .bashrc with your text editor again and replace
>   the alias for "today" with the following:
>
> ```
> today() {
>     echo -n "Today's date is: "
>     date +"%A, %B %-d, %Y"
> }
> ```

The line I am supposed to replace is `'date +"%A, %B %-d, %Y"'`

The full line being:

`alias today='date +"%A, %B %-d, %Y"'`

However, having tried the following:

```
alias today='today() { 
                echo -n "Today's date is: "
                date +"%A, %B %-d, %Y"
             }'
```

With and without the apostrophe on the 2nd line(in "Today's"), and w/wo the enclosing single quotes, as a one liner, and using the `function` keyword combined with all the other options listed. I also tried to define the function above the alias statement and then simply use 'today()'(w/wo quotes) as the alias value, as a long shot. None of the above is working.

What is the correct syntax here to use this function as the alias?

Comment: In fact, you then don't need to create an alias. Since you defined the function in .bashrc, you have access to it by just using its name (and hypothetical parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That snippet isn't telling you to do anything with the `alias` but delete it.

It is trying to have you replace the alias with a function since functions are generally more useful than aliases.

Comment: I see, so I don't need to provide the 'alias=' part at all for 'today' to work from the command line. Nice!

Comment: Now I know how to do this right, AND the snippet makes sense to me. Thanks

Comment: Correct. Aliases are short-hand for longer commands but they are limited in what they can do and where arguments to them can be used. functions are significantly more useful and can be used in exactly the same ways as aliases. And yes, both aliases and functions are available at the shell prompt.

Answer (score 2):

You can have it separately:

```
_today() { echo -n "Today's date is: "; date +"%A, %B %-d, %Y"; }
alias today='_today'
```